# Are questions seeking attorneys with specialized experience in a narrow area of the law on topic here

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, attorneys who have experience in 42 USC 1983?   That seems to be a very specialized topic of civil rights law.   According to one reference, it is a statute for redressing constitutional and federal statutory violations by state and local officials, by municipalities, and by private-party state actors

I'm looking for an attorney who can demonstrate knowledge of and success with this statute, or at a minimum one who finds the topic interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Requests for experts or attorney referrals are definitely *not* on-topic here.

What follows is just my own notes and opinion:

There are many attorney referral sites and services online and elsewhere.  [Avvo.com](https://www.avvo.com/find-a-lawyer) is well-known for this, and there are plenty more referral sites like [this](https://www.freeadvice.com/).  Almost every [bar association](https://www.americanbar.org) offers referral services.  There are (or have been) sites like [LegalBid](https://www.legalbids.com) for this purpose.  [Nolo.com](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/find-lawyer-how-to-find-attorney-29868.html) has a section devoted to this.  Plenty of articles on this with links: e.g., [here](https://lifehacker.com/5826959/how-to-find-a-reputable-lawyer) and [here](https://hirealawyer.findlaw.com/choosing-the-right-lawyer/where-to-find-a-lawyer.html).

FYI: Section 1983 is one of the most common statutes used for civil rights lawsuits against government entities.  Any "civil-rights lawyer" will be familiar with it.

Comment: I understand, but to clarify I'm familiar with Avvo etc.   These seem primarily to be self-serving advertising by attorneys, but I've made contact attempts through Avvo in particular.   None of the attorneys who responded who seemed well qualified.  I'll look at your other links.   Thanks.

Comment: @Burt_Harris: Yeah, I have never found a reliable general source or method for finding what I consider to be a good attorney for a specific purpose.  And it's not for lack of looking!  I'd say an information inefficiency like this is a great business opportunity ... except that at least in the U.S. the profession has proven resistant to such efforts.